# How to scrape images from eBay and Amazon using XPath in Nokogiri from JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape images from websites using Nokogiri and XPath, so far with limited success.  For a typical website whose HTML has `img` and `src`, I can use:

```
tmp2 = Nokogiri::HTML(open(site_url))
tmp2.xpath("//img/@src").each do |src|
  ...do whatever
end
```

However, some sites like Amazon and eBay only trigger certain images with JavaScript.  If I look at the code I can see the data in arrays.  For example, from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00T46V758):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
P.when('jQuery', 'cf').execute(function($, cf){
  P.load.js('http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/browser-scripts/imageBlock-udp-airy/imageBlock-udp-airy-4060168860._V1_.js');
});

P.when('A', 'jQuery', 'ImageBlockATF', 'cf').register('ImageBlockBTF', function(A, $, imageBlockATF, cf){
  var data = {"indexToColor":[],"burjImageBlock":0,"isSwatchHoverConsistent":1,"heroFocalPoint":null,"visualDimensions":["color_name"],"productGroupID":"apparel_display_on_website","newVideoMissing":0,"useIV":0,"useClickZoom":null,"useChildVideos":0,"numColors":7,"logMetrics":0,"defaultColor":"initial","airyConfig":{"enableContinuousPlay":null,"installFlashButtonText":"Install Flash Player","contentTitle":null,"autoplayCutOffTimeSeconds":null,"ageGate":{"monthNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],"deniedPrompt":"We're sorry. You are not old enough to watch this video.","submitText":"Submit","prompt":"This video is not intended for all audiences. What date were you born?"},"videoAds":null,"videoUnsupportedPrompt":"Sorry, this video is unsupported on this browser.","desiredMode":null,"swfUrl":"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/vap/video/airy2/prod/2.0.1102.0/flash/AiryBasicRenderer._V304902271_.swf","isAutoplayEnabled":null,"installFlashPrompt":"Adobe Flash Player is required to watch this video.","isLiveStream":null,"regionCode":"NA","contentId":null,"playbackErrorPrompt":"Sorry, an error has occurred while attempting video playback. Please try again later.","contentMinAge":null,"isForesterTrackingDisabled":null,"streamingUrls":null,"parentId":null,"foresterMetadataParams":{"client":"Dpx","requestId":"1MX7VHFRVAS6TWY64BXC","marketplaceId":"ATVPDKIKX0DER","session":"182-9511970-7757812","method":"Apparel.ImageBlock"},"jsUrl":"http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/vap/video/airy2/prod/2.0.1102.0/js/airy.chromeless._V304902265_.js"},"mainImageMaxSizes":null,"staticStrings":{"playVideo":"Click to play video","rollOverToZoom":"Roll over image to zoom in","images":"Images","video":"video","clickToZoom":"Click on image to zoom in","touchToZoom":"Touch the image to zoom in","videos":"Videos","close":"Close","pleaseSelect":"Please select","clickToExpand":"Click to open expanded view","allMedia":"All Media"},"notThumbnailClickImmersiveView":1,"gIsNewTwister":1,"title":"Threads 4 Thought Women's Tabitha Basic Tank Top","ivRepresentativeAsin":{"6":"B00T46V76W","4":"B00WM3O7ES","1":"B00T46YZES","3":"B00WM3NLPE","2":"B00T46VD16","5":"B00T46VGXQ"},"mainImageSizes":[[342,445],[385,500],[425,550],[466,606],[522,679]],"isQuickview":0,"ipadVideoSizes":[[340,444],[384,500]],"colorToAsin":{"Coral Dreams":{"asin":"B00T46V76W"},"Heather Grey":{"asin":"B00WM3NLPE"},"Black":{"asin":"B00T46YZES"},"White":{"asin":"B00T46VGXQ"},"Deep Blue Sea":{"asin":"B00T46VD16"},"Sea Glass":{"asin":"B00WM3O7ES"}},"thumbExperimentEnabledValue":1,"showLITBOnClick":0,"videoSizes":[[342,445],[384,500]],"stretchyGoodnessWidth":[1280,1440,1640,1800],"autoplayVideo":0,"hoverZoomIndicator":"","sitbReftag":"","useHoverZoom":1,"staticImages":{"zoomOut":"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/detail-page/cursors/zoom-out._V184888738_.bmp","hoverZoomIcon":"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img11/apparel/UX/DP/icon_zoom._V138923886_.png","zoomIn":"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/detail-page/cursors/zoom-in._V184888790_.bmp","zoomLensBackground":"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/apparel/rcxgs/tile._V211431200_.gif","videoThumbIcon":"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/Quarterdeck/en_US/images/video._V183716339_SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.gif","spinner":"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/ui/loadIndicators/loading-large_labeled._V192238949_.gif","zoomInCur":"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/detail-page/cursors/zoomIn._V323082799_.cur","videoSWFPath":"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/Quarterdeck/en_US/video/20110518115040892/Video._V178668404_.swf","arrow":"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/javascripts/lib/popover/images/light/sprite-vertical-popover-arrow._V186877868_.png","zoomOutCur":"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/detail-page/cursors/zoomOut._V323082798_.cur"},"videos":[],"gPreferChildVideos":0,"altsOnLeft":1,"ivImageSetKeys":{"Coral Dreams":"6","Heather Grey":"3","Black":"1","initial":0,"White":"5","Deep Blue Sea":"2","Sea Glass":"4"},"useHoverZoomIpad":"","isUDP":1,"alwaysIncludeVideo":0,"widths":[1280,1440,1640,1800],"maxAlts":7,"useChromelessVideoPlayer":1,"mainImageHeightPartitions":null};
  data["customerImages"] = eval('[]');
  data["colorImages"] = {"Coral Dreams":[{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41FGlhksmtL.jpg","variant":"MAIN","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81iXQbkcpiL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41FGlhksmtL._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81iXQbkcpiL._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81iXQbkcpiL._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81iXQbkcpiL._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81iXQbkcpiL._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81iXQbkcpiL._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"]}},{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41XR9o0cV-L.jpg","variant":"BACK","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81bVmFiRu0L._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41XR9o0cV-L._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81bVmFiRu0L._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81bVmFiRu0L._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81bVmFiRu0L._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81bVmFiRu0L._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81bVmFiRu0L._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"]}}],"Heather Grey":[{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41f-8R8Eu-L.jpg","variant":"MAIN","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81dTYkBL%2BxL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41f-8R8Eu-L._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81dTYkBL%2BxL._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81dTYkBL%2BxL._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81dTYkBL%2BxL._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81dTYkBL%2BxL._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81dTYkBL%2BxL._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"]}},{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41gLiFBbcdL.jpg","variant":"BACK","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81ua3AXCpJL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41gLiFBbcdL._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81ua3AXCpJL._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81ua3AXCpJL._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81ua3AXCpJL._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81ua3AXCpJL._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81ua3AXCpJL._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"]}}],"Black":[{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41BxSpfEM7L.jpg","variant":"MAIN","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2BTW8762BL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41BxSpfEM7L._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2BTW8762BL._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2BTW8762BL._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2BTW8762BL._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2BTW8762BL._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2BTW8762BL._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"]}},{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Gf%2BW-cPTL.jpg","variant":"BACK","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81SJwuaCspL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Gf%2BW-cPTL._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81SJwuaCspL._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81SJwuaCspL._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81SJwuaCspL._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81SJwuaCspL._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81SJwuaCspL._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"]}}],"White":[{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41tElK2wPKL.jpg","variant":"MAIN","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81kKgU75rIL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41tElK2wPKL._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81kKgU75rIL._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81kKgU75rIL._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81kKgU75rIL._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81kKgU75rIL._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81kKgU75rIL._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"]}},{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31lEDIs4cqL.jpg","variant":"BACK","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OBgvbUR7L._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31lEDIs4cqL._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OBgvbUR7L._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OBgvbUR7L._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OBgvbUR7L._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OBgvbUR7L._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OBgvbUR7L._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"]}}],"Deep Blue Sea":[{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41oNq3KmSGL.jpg","variant":"MAIN","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81MtZtmxVLL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41oNq3KmSGL._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81MtZtmxVLL._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81MtZtmxVLL._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81MtZtmxVLL._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81MtZtmxVLL._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81MtZtmxVLL._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"]}},{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41AJgd1OuYL.jpg","variant":"BACK","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81uLEksrYFL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41AJgd1OuYL._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81uLEksrYFL._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81uLEksrYFL._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81uLEksrYFL._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81uLEksrYFL._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81uLEksrYFL._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"]}}],"Sea Glass":[{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418vg-re8oL.jpg","variant":"MAIN","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81YgtD-bEwL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418vg-re8oL._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81YgtD-bEwL._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81YgtD-bEwL._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81YgtD-bEwL._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81YgtD-bEwL._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81YgtD-bEwL._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"]}},{"large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41lcpC41VSL.jpg","variant":"BACK","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/814%2B6ZLwIxL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41lcpC41VSL._SR38,50_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/814%2B6ZLwIxL._UY500_.jpg":["385","500"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/814%2B6ZLwIxL._UX342_.jpg":["342","445"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/814%2B6ZLwIxL._UX522_.jpg":["522","679"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/814%2B6ZLwIxL._UX466_.jpg":["466","606"],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/814%2B6ZLwIxL._UY550_.jpg":["423","550"]}}]};
  data["heroImage"] = {};
  data["landingAsinColor"] = 'Coral Dreams';
  data["shouldApplyResizeFix"] = false;

  return data;
});

</script>
```

The filenames I want to grab don't have `src` (i.e. `http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2BTW8762BL._UY500_.jpg`)  In this case, the array is called `data["colorImages"]`. But I can't hard-code anything because the same thing happens on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Summer-Women-Casual-Chiffon-Loose-Tops-Batwing-Short-Sleeve-Loose-T-Shirt-Blouse-/351411949784?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&var=&hash=item51d1c8d0d8).

The filenames I need here are in `enImgCarousel`.

On a side note, when I use the following JavaScript bookmarklet for each URL to get images, I'm able to get the correct images:

```
a='';
for (b=0;b<document.images.length;b++){
  a+='<img src='+document.images[b].src+'><br>'};
  ifa=''){
    document.writea+'</center>');
    void(document.close())
  }else{
    alert('No images!')
  }
```

Back to Nokogiri and XPath, I've also tried:

```
tmp2.xpath("//img").each do |src|...
```

and

```
 tmp2.xpath("html//img").each do |src|
```

Any ideas how I should do this or which direction to go in?

Comment: A couple things: Don't scrape sites that have APIs available to you and who prohibit scraping in their TOS, you can get banned which would break any app you build, and you'll waste a lot of your and their CPU retrieving junk just to mine a little useful data, which is why they have APIs. Nokogiri can't help you much if they're using Dynamic HTML except to return the string containing the JavaScript or JSON. From that point you have to decipher it yourself. And, if the data is loaded by AJAX you need to use different tools. Again, all this points to your need to use the APIs.

Answer (score -1):

This is alternative way to solve what you want; you can use Capybara and Poltergeist.

I assume you don't have to dive into JavaScript with this solution.

If you scrape, I recommend that you consider Capybara with Poltergeist, you can find many sources to reference.

This is the code I tried:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_debug do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, inspector: true)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist_debug
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist_debug 

# Amazon Case
visit_site('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00T46V758/?tag=stackoverfl08-20')
doc_amazon = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(page.html)
doc_amazon.xpath("//img/@src").each do |src|
  p src.value  
end 

#ebay case
visit_site('https://www.ebay.com/itm/Summer-Women-Casual-Chiffon-Loose-Tops-Batwing-Short-Sleeve-Loose-T-Shirt-Blouse-/351411949784?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&var=&hash=item51d1c8d0d8')    
doc_ebay = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(page.html)
doc_ebay.xpath("//img/@src").each do |src|
  p src.value  
end
```

If you want to dig into it:

```
doc.xpath("//div[@id='imgTagWrapperId']/img").attribute('src').value
# => "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2BTW8762BL._UX453_.jpg"

 doc.xpath("//div[@id='mainImgHldr']/img[@id='icImg']").attribute('src').value
# => "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/dtAAAOSwpdpVZuU~/s-l300.jpg"
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. I'd recommend try running it, fixing it and editing the answer with the working code.

Comment: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)"

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, as I am posting the answer from mobile phone, I can't write full code right away, however, I can give you a way. You should use [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) with selenium-webdriver & watir instead of only Nokogiri.

Using Mechanize, you will be able to handle elements coming from JavaScript. You can mock the actual moves on browser i.e. you can code for clicking on links/buttons, you can wait for image load and then can scrape it. And all this can be done using Mechanize very easily.

Comment: Mechanize won't execute any JavaScript, so it can't "handle elements coming from JavaScript". It is possible to click buttons, but if those trigger any JavaScript actions, or JavaScript tries to dynamically modify a page those changes won't be seen. Turn off JavaScript in the browser and navigate through the site and you'll see what Mechanize will see.

Comment: @theTinMan As mentioned in the answer, you need to use mechanize with selenium-webdriver and watir to handle dynamic elements

Comment: If you are using selenium or watir then Mechanize isn't necessary. Use those to navigate and Nokogiri because it is the parsing core of Mechanize and is lighter weight.

Comment: Yep, makes sense. We can go that way too by using nokogiri with selenium and watir, however, personally, I feel mechanize easy to use and code with.

Answer (score -2):

Are you trying to generate a database of competitors items with pricing, etc.?
Are you trying to grab entire categories or individual sellers? 
The reason why I ask is you can get an RSS feed of items each seller lists if they have turned that feature on.  This way, you do not have to waste time scraping a page when you can get the central data from an RSS feed.

When parsing webpages, depending upon where you are in the webpage (you mentioned carousel) the indices you are encountering are from the stash of thumbnails representing the larger images.
I recommend looking at the eBay API and the Amazon API and finding the RSS feeds for the sellers first.

As far as getting past any Javascript issues, the webpage loads rotating slideshows and carousels dynamically, so you will have to use Mechanize (as RAJ suggested above) or Beautiful Soup or Selenium to get fully rendered web pages in which all images are in a scrapable state.

Feel free to post your source if there is anything else I can help with.

Comment: The issue I'm facing is that a user can ask to get images from any website, not just eBay and Amazon. For most sites, regular scraping of images (per the code I have above) works great; but for some sites (and I won't know in advance which ones), I'd need something to scrape deeper. What I would need is to look at the page code and return all image files listed (not just those with img src attributes). The bounty expires in a few minutes and I wish I could extend it as I haven't had time to try Mechanize yet though it does sound promising. I haven't heard of Beautiful Soup. I will look into it

Comment: Any program which specifically "renders" the javascript will resolve this issue because it removes the indexing, etc. and gives you the pictures and other javascript referenced items explicitly.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer so I can receive the bounty before the grace period expires - - thanks!

Comment: Hi minscule. I wrote: "I need an answer I can use to help me solve this. For this bounty, please make sure the answer is not general but includes a detailed explanation, or better yet, example code." so I'm not really sure who to give it to as you basically told me the same thing as RAJ yet neither answer has code that I was hoping to see.

Comment: Since you are essentially moving to a different solution, I would feel better if you gave the bounty to RAJ since he pointed out the first working solution.  Going with my RSS feed solution would simply augment what you are doing now and lower your processing overhead.  The rendering we both referred to is common, so RAJ was first to the summit.

Comment: @miniscule: See "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/what-happens-if-you-answered-a-question-questioner-says-thanks-but-didnt-acce)" and "[Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat)"