# Web scraping with xpath jsonpath or anything else to pull filenames that end with .jpg

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, xpath, web-scraping, jsonpath

This is another request for help as my [1st question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682191/ruby-on-rails-xpath-json-scraping-images/30843277?noredirect=1#comment49762000_30843277) was never really answered. I'm going to try a different approach here...

I need to be able to scrape all image *filenames* from a site.
 I'm using Ruby on Rails with Nokogiri (and Mechanize also). I can get the page.
However, once I get the page, I can't figure out how to use xpath to get the filenames I need (I'd love to be able to use begins-with "http://" and ends-with ".jpg" but haven't been able to figure out how).

An example url is the notorious Amazon product page:  [http://www.amazon.com/Alternative-Womens-Jersey-Twist-Asymmetrical/dp/B00SM7E8EC/ref=sr_1_14?s=apparel&ie=UTF8&qid=1435518992&sr=1-14](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00SM7E8EC)

The main product opens with a pink dress but I also want the gray and black dresses.  Using xpath's `//img/@src` I can get the pink dress but not the other two. (On a side note, when I try xpath's `//img` in my Chrome's XPather add-on, I get a lot of images returned but when I try to use just `//img` in Ruby I get an error; the exact code is:

```
tmp2 = Nokogiri::HTML(open(recommendation_url))
   tmp2.xpath('//img/@src').each do |i_img|
end
```

One more thing, when I create a bookmarklet that runs the following javascript code on amazon pages it works great!!:

```
    for (a=0;a<document.images.length;a++){
       x+='<img src='+document.images[a].src+'><br>'};
       if(x!='' {
          document.write('<center>'+x+'</center>');
          void(document.close())
       }else{
          alert('No images!')
       }
     }
```

My ideal solution would either be:
1. Figure out the xpath (or would jsonpath be better?) above
2. Be able to run this javascript code from Ruby on Rails

Can someone help?